# Two different classes using accepts_nested_attributes of one class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a class Addresse where Organismereferent and Organisme have a `has_many` `belongs_to` relationship with. Also Organismereferent and Organisme can `accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses`

My problem is when I only had the Organismereferent class everything was working fine and I was able to create a new Organismereferent with an addresse but as soon as I created and added the same relation to Organisme , they both stopped working without giving any error message I only get this in the console:
[image]

My model:

```
class Organismereferent < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :addresses
  has_many :referents
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses
end

class Organisme < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :addresses
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses
end

class Address < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :organismereferent
  belongs_to :organisme
end
```

Controller for Organisme

```
def new
  @organisme = Organisme.new
  @organisme.addresses.build
end

def create
  @organisme = Organisme.new(organisme_params)
  @organisme.status = true
  @organisme.save
  redirect_to @organisme
end

private
  def organisme_params
    params.require(:organisme).permit(:nom, :telephone, :courriel, :fax, addresses_attributes: [:id, :no_civique, :rue, :ville, :province, :etat, :code_postal])
  end
```

Controller for Organismereferent:

```
def new
  @organisme = Organismereferent.new
  @organisme.addresses.build
end

def create
  @organisme = Organismereferent.new(organisme_params)
  @organisme.active = true
  @organisme.save
  redirect_to @organisme
end

private
  def organisme_params
      params.require(:organismereferent).permit(:nom_organisation, :bureau, :telecopie, :courriel, :site_web, addresses_attributes: [:id, :no_civique, :rue, :ville, :province, :etat, :code_postal])
  end
```

I'm not sure what else information might be important so I'll be glad to add anything.

Comment: Could you show us the error message?. `@organisme.save!` will show the error message.

Comment: @JunanChakma It gives me this `Validation failed: Addresses organisme must exist`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change address model like

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :organismereferent, optional: true
  belongs_to :organisme, optional: true
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works perfectly :D Was it because it was trying to have both of them for each addresses and by adding that they're optional it allows it to have only one of them?

Comment: It was not worked because `Address` validate to presence `organisme` while create it. But since its parents `organisme` has not created yet while creating `address`. Thats why it is giving this validation error.